# attach a vCard to an event in an iCalendar file with vpim gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, icalendar, vcf-vcard, vpim

Is anyone familiar with the vPim gem
(https://github.com/sam-github/vpim)?
I've been successful creating different iCalendars and vCards. However,
I'm
trying to attach a vCard to an event in an iCalendar file. This article
describes exactly why and how I want to do this:
http://mobicontact.info/iphone/download-contact-from-web-page/ . I can't
seem to find or understand any documentation on how this is done with
vPim.
There are references to this capability in the docs but not very well
explained: http://rubydoc.info/gems/vpim/0.695/frames .

I'm using this in Rails 3.2.8 w/ Ruby 1.9.3

BIG thanks in advance for any help.